# Got 'Connection Refused' error when i tried to connect Third party services using Proxy in Mule Anypointstudio

Tags: mule

> 

```html
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="nww.neopost.sbs.nhs.uk" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" proxy-ref="Neopost_Global_Proxy_Configuration">
     <http:basic-authentication username="46234F3D-192C-4118-9A79-948F6C2053BB" password="F25038E0-53D6-4C06-8DFE-FF25FA3C82CD"/>
     <tls:context>
         <tls:trust-store path="C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/security/cacerts" password="changeit"/>
     </tls:context>
 </http:request-config>
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8088" basePath="test" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
 <flow name="xxxFlow">
     <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
     <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="web_api_dev/documentservices.svc/Documents" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
         <http:request-builder>
             <http:query-param paramName="batchsize" value="100"/>
         </http:request-builder>
     </http:request>
     <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
 </flow>
```

When i tried to connect third party services using anypoint studio project, it gives me 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information' error. I have checked the proxy and added that host in proxy bypass also. But still am getting same error.

I am accessible third party url using browser, but not with "https request".

Help me to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

**Anypointstudio_proxy_settings**

[image]

**Browser_proxy_Settings**

[image]

**Browser_Response**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mule flows do not use the Anypoint Studio proxy configuration. Your http:request-config element has specified proxy-ref="Neopost_Global_Proxy_Configuration", you need to remove that if you want to connect to that host directly.

If you have multiple HTTP Requests, some that need to use the proxy and some that don't, you will need to have 2 different http:request-config elements.

Comment: Thanks for your response Clinton, with out 'proxy-ref' it is working fine.But when this application move into the production 'proxy-ref' is mandatory.

Comment: Your Anypoint Studio configuration says you want to bypass the proxy for this URL. Are you saying that you need to connect directly and can't use the proxy from your development environment, but must use the proxy in production. If this is that case, try creating 2 http:request-config elements, one with the proxy and one without, and then using environment properties to choose which one you refer to from http:request